# Signal multiplier circuit using op amp concepts

Tags: operational-amplifier, ltspice, signal, frequency, multiplier

> Design a circuit that from two sinusoidal inputs generates the output \$s(t) = \sin(2π f_1 t) \times \sin(2π f_2 t)\$, where \$f_1\$ and \$f_2\$ are two distinct frequencies between 1 kHz and 10 kHz. To design your circuit, based on op-amp topologies {adder, subtractor, positive and negative feedback, and unity follower}. Simulate your circuit by showing \$x(t)\$ for various values of \$f_1\$ and \$f_2\$.

I built this circuit, but it doesn't have the correct output and I can't make it have the output with the product of the signals.

[image]

The concept of the problem would be to assemble this proposed circuit without using a diode, only with an op amp. How can I do it?

Comment: That circuit does not multiply. It can't be done only with an op-amp.

Comment: I strongly suggest you copy the question verbatim because, what you have written does not make sense grammatically. The devil is usually in the detail etc.. Bad/disfunctional grammer = `To design your circuit, based on op-amp topologies {adder, subtractor, positive and negative feedback, and unity follower}`

Comment: Looks like a trick question to me ... but it DOES have an answer! Hint : go back to an elementary math course on trigonometric identities. Hint 2 : Question doesn't explicitly tell you say what two input frequencies you must use... I'll let you take it from there.